# PDO bindcolum statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm doing a register code for my website and I'm blocked on the part of doing the PDO::bindcolumn part.
Here is the code I've written:

This is my register.php

```
<fieldset id="registrarse"> <form method="post" action="register2.php">
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"><br>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <label>Correo electrónico:</label>
    <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Correo electrónico"><br>
    <label>Género:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Hombre">Hombre
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Mujer">Mujer<br>
    <p id="letra">Esto es para asociar un diseño masculino o femenino</p>
    <input type="submit" value="¡Regístrate!">
    <input type="reset" value="Resetear campos"> </form> </fieldset>
```

And this is my register2.php:

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=localhost;dbname=crespo;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT into users (username, password, mail, sex) VALUES (:username, :password, :mail, :sex)");
$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$_POST['username'],
                    ':password'=>$_POST['password'],
                    ':mail'=>$_POST['mail'],
                    ':sex'=>$_POST['sex']));
?>
```

Now I'm stucked and I don't know what to do. I've been following an example from the official PDO manual from php.net, but I don't know what to do next.
I think it's something like `$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);` so, what do I have to do now?

Thanks.

Comment: What else do you want to do? Your rows is already inserted in your databse

Comment: @Fabio No, when I fill in the form, nothing happens in my db... And I think if I use the bindColumn statement, I make my db insertion more secure, am I right?

Comment: @davidstrachan OP *is* using lazy binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything *looks* good, so if your rows are not being inserted then there is probably some sort of error going on, but since you don't have any sort of error reporting turned on, you will never see it. When dealing with PDO, there are three places that you should look for errors:

**Number 1:**

Put the following at the top of *any* PHP script during debugging to see all errors:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Number 2:**

PDO could fail when connecting. You need to handle this:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('dblib:host=localhost;dbname=crespo;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed';
}
```

**Number 3:**

By default, [PDO handles errors silently](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) which means that the script will continue to execute, but you won't see any sort of error. To let errors show up, you need to set the error mode. You can either do it by passing it as an argument to the [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) or after the connection is made, like this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

As I mentioned above, using prepared statements prevents you from SQL injection. What it doesn't prevent you from is insecurely storing passwords in plain text, which is a very bad idea. [Hash them](http://php.net/password_hash).

**Edit:**

Since you are having problem with the connection, you are using invalid login credentials. With MySQL, the DSN should look like:

```
'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test'
```

Notice the `mysql` at the beginning. `dblib` is for Sybase databases. I would try changing `dblib` to `mysql` and see if that fixes your problem. If not, in your `catch` block, echo `$e->getMessage()` to show what the server actually says. Just remove it once you get it connected because it can reveal your login credentials.

Comment: Oh, thanks for replying! I've added the code and it gives me the error 'Connection failed' so I'm afraid there's some error in my db connection. What's wrong with it? I use phpmyadmin with localhost in my Ubuntu.

Comment: Yep, I've already tried changing it to 'mysql', and also changing the values (with values I mean host, dbname...) with variables, so it looks like this: ''mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass)', but it shows me the same error 'Connection failed'

Comment: What does `echo $e->getMessage();` display?

Comment: Connection failed SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '$host', and in the $host variable I have localhost

Comment: That's not the code that you posted at the beginning. There you put `localhost` right into the DSN and now you're saying it's a variable. If that's the case, change the single quotes to double quotes or else the variables aren't parsed by PHP.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it like the initial code and removed the charset:UTF-8 part because it gave me an error, so now it looks like this: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crespo', $user, $pass); and it doesn't give me any error but it doesn't upload anything to the db.

Comment: Put this after your insert: `print_r($db->errorInfo());`

Comment: Okay, it prints this: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: `00000` indicates that your query was successful.

Comment: Mmmmm.... So it looks like something is missing in the PDO code for inserting it into the db, am I right? Because in my db there's nothing new.

Comment: If what you have at the beginning is what you are executing, you aren't missing anything. Are you sure you're looking at the right DB?

Comment: Also, make sure your `$_POST` values are correct. Maybe they are empty so it's inserting empty values into the DB.

Comment: Yes, I think they're right! I made a $username = $_POST['username']; and then a echo of $username and it returned the username I wrote in my form!

Comment: Okay, I've already resolved it, it was an error in my db, I had a wrong name.